# If $\mathcal F$ a $\sigma -$algebra and $X$ a collection of subset, does $X\subset \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal F\subset X$ implies $X=\mathcal F$?

Tags: probability

Let $\mathcal F$ a $\sigma -$algebra on $\Omega $ and let $X$ a collection of subset of $\Omega $. If $X\subset \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal F\subset X$ does $X=\mathcal F$ ? (in other words, does $X$ is automatically a $\sigma -$algebra ?).

Comment: That's precisely the definition of two sets being equal.

Answer (score 2):

Of course $X \subset \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal F \subset X$ implies $\mathcal F = X$.